# Working script for copied files

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a form with an installed trigger (`onFormSubmit`) I want to copy for mutliple people: "Form person X", "Form person Y"...

The copied form should behave exactly the same as the source. Currently I am using the function [`makeCopy(name, destination)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makecopyname-destination) to do this. The problem is that the installed trigger is not copied, and it looks like using the `newTrigger(functionName)` if the script is not run in the script editor for the new form is not adding the trigger.

```
formFile.makeCopy(newFileName, formFolder);
var newFile = formFolder.getFilesByName(newFileName).next();
var newFileId = newFile.getId();

var newForm = FormApp.openById(newFileId);
newForm.setTitle(newFileName);
ScriptApp.newTrigger("onFormSubmit")
    .forForm(newForm)
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create();
```

The reason for this might be that you have to allow the script to access the apps, if this is the case is there a way to solve this without having to open the script for every new form?

### Edit

I noticed that when I answer the form of "person X" the source form gets modified. This is pretty strange because I am using the `source` form of the ObjectEvent.

Comment: The `makeCopy()` method returns a file, which is the new copied file.  You "should" be able to use `var newFile = formFile.makeCopy(newFileName, formFolder);`  instead of getting all files by the name of the new file.  So, you should not need that second line of code at all.  If this is a bug, you'd need to put together the steps needed for someone else to reproduce the problem and report it to the Apps Script Issue tracker.

Comment: Thank you for that hint but it looks like this is not the cause. I found out tha t all the triggers are created for the form the script editor was opened from, meaning that something is probably going wrong with the [forForm(String)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-builder#forForm(String)) function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way it works is very likely WAI.

The `source` of the form submit EventObject is defined as

> A Form object, representing the Google Forms file to which the script is bound

[*Source*](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_3)

As the script is still bound to the "base" form it will return the base form as source even if another form is calling the function.

Functions adding a trigger to a document, spreadsheet or form (for example `forForm(Form form)`) only work for the document, spreadsheet or form the add-on belongs to

> Add-ons can only create triggers for the document or spreadsheet in which the add-on is used. That is, an add-on that is used in Google Doc A cannot create a trigger to monitor when Google Doc B is opened.

[*Source*](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#limitations)

A work around might be to add to the newly created form a required checkbox with only one value being the id of the form. You can then use the id while reading the FormResponse.